# I've problems with my thesis and don't compile, Do you help me? Where is the error?

Tags: equations, errors, compiling, compilation-error, error-bars

My thesis don't compile and i don't understand the reason. It's an physics undergraduation final thesis. Help me because i don't understand the errors from the log and the true reason

if you wish speak with me you for more details, can use my telegram account: @lucas_xavier_127443 (i speak portuguese and english only)

THE .TEX ARCHIVES:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rr08bedrP7kyX8qh9wEkZ_103SWAOF-0/view?usp=sharing

i'm grateful for the help

Comment: you should use xelatex or lualatex for the combilation. pdflatex won't work.

Comment: you should post the log instead of redirecting us to an external site (who knows what we might find around the net).

Answer (score 1):

You wrote,

> i don't understand the errors from the log [file]

The log file contains the following error message:

```
! Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or
(fontspec)                      LuaTeX.
(fontspec)                      
(fontspec)                      You must change your typesetting engine to,
(fontspec)                      e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex" instead of
(fontspec)                      "latex" or "pdflatex".
```

The remedy? Don't use pdfLaTeX to compile this particular document. Because your document loads the `fontspec` package, you *must* use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Mico, with ou without fontspec don't work i will show my .tex archives to see the errors

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rr08bedrP7kyX8qh9wEkZ_103SWAOF-0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @LucasXavier - It's not a matter of "with or without fontspec". The issue is that if your document loads `fontspec`, you cannot compile it successfully under pdfLaTeX.

Comment: @LucasXavier - The google doc isn't accessible.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Rr08bedrP7kyX8qh9wEkZ_103SWAOF-0/view?usp=sharing

Mico, use this link, i corrected the privilegies

i tryed with lualatex and xelatex and don't compile and without **fontspec** dont't work too ( i tryed lualatex, xelatex and pdflatex)

Comment: @LucasXavier - Sorry, but I will *never* open zip files from sources I'm not familiar with personally.

Comment: no problem, without .zip archives
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1AaLryjIigNgYBWId9ws1CDt1q9MHmUZg?usp=sharing 
this link is a folder only

Comment: @LucasXavier  - May I ask you to post a *new query* with the information about the specific document class and the specific preamble you employ, and wirh more specific for the help you're looking for? (There are a quite a few syntax errors in your files. No wonder your document doesn't compile.)

Comment: yes, i understood but i don't understand the specific reason to error syntax, do you say that i need to open a new query about syntax erros?

Comment: @LucasXavier - In a word, yes.